# How to create strcuture folder with gulp

Tags: gulp

I'd like to create my initial structure folders in web project using gulp, Are there is any package that help me to make this task ?

Example:

```
-css
-img
--content
--icons
-fonts
-js
```

with one command in bash create that strcuture

Comment: Gulp is a build tool. You could probably write a task to do that, but it's not really the best fit. A couple suggestions: a) write a plain old bash script for it. or b) Look a scaffolding tool for it. I personally don't tend to use them, but Yeoman and Slush are two I know of for node.js-based projects. Further reading: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-project-scaffolding-with-gulp-and-slush

Comment: @Alexander, You've asked a lot of questions and never marked any as correct? Theres a green tick next to all answers that you are meant to select to help others. Heres a helpful link for you http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 21):

Gulp can create structure folders without any package with this trick:

```
gulp.task('directories', function () {
    return gulp.src('*.*', {read: false})
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./img'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./img/content'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./img/icons'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./fonts'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));
});
```

Comment: read: false will exclude files but reads folders. In my cast the folders in the source folder are created in each dest folder.

Comment: This is beautiful. 

Minor comment: I'd insert a

`.pipe(gulp.dest('./img'))`

after the `./css` line because it won't create `./img/content` or `./img/icons` unless `./img` exists first.

Answer (score 10):

You can use fs ([Node.js - File System](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html))

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const fs   = require('fs');


gulp.task('default', () => {

    const folders = [
        'css',
        'img',
        'img/content',
        'img/icons',
        'fonts',
        'js'
    ];

    folders.forEach(dir => {
        if(!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(dir);
            console.log('  folder created:', dir);    
        }   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the cmd to create directories is `mkdir`

So you could create a gulp task using [gulp-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell) to create your folder structure.

---

EDIT for comment

```
  gulp.task('directory', function () {
    return gulp.src('*.js', {read: false})
    .pipe(shell([
      'mkdir -p  css img img/content img/icons fonts js'
    ]));
  });
```

This will output

```
css
img
| - content
| - icons
fonts
js
```

---

```
  gulp.task('directory', function () {
    return gulp.src('*.js', {read: false})
    .pipe(shell([
      'mkdir -css -img --content --icons -fonts -js'
    ]));
  });
```

Comment: I don't think that the dashes are intentional. The content and icons folders are under the img folder